# How to get all Bars of london by google radar api

Tags: php, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

How to get all Bars of london by google radar api ? I'm getting only 182 bars
This is my php code:
This is simple CURL request , why I'm not getting more results by this API request ? Or is there any more API call to get all records ?

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=51.5073509%2C-0.1277583&radius=100000&types=bar&keyword=Bars%20In%20United%20Kingdom&key=MY_KEY",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "authorization: Basic Qm94T2ZmaWNlVGhlYXRyZTozcFBOcVNwN1E3QW1Id2NB",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "postman-token: 670a688b-142e-d8d3-ad62-1fe3c8320d6f",
    "x-calendly-hook-id: 25958",
    "x-token: OGPAFCIEDNOLMVUHD5MDTLJCJ2MLVZYG"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Comment: Could you show some code ([mcve])?

Comment: Code posted , please see again

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#radar_search_requests): *a call to the PlacesService's radarSearch() method will return an array of up to 200 PlaceResult objects*. You will need to perform serveral queries to get more results

Comment: Also from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#radar_search_requests): *The maximum allowed radius is **50 000** meters.*